# Parse yaml file content to scss via ruby

Tags: ruby, sass, yaml

I am trying to obtain the contents of a yaml (.yml) file in my scss. The aim is to make the contents of the yaml file available as an SCSS map, so the values can be read and iterated over.

So far I have this:

SCSS file:

```
$ranges: yaml_load('path/to/file');
```

Ruby file (a hacked version of [this gem](https://github.com/fabiofabbrucci/sass-yaml)):

```
require 'yaml'

module Sass::Script::Functions
  def yaml_load(file_name)
    # Required because the filename is escaped: "\"path/to/file.yml\""
    file_name = file_name.to_s[1..-2]
    if (File.file?(file_name))
      file_content = YAML::load_file(file_name)

      if (file_content.is_a?(Hash))
        p 'is indeed a hash'
        return Sass::Script::Value::Map.new(file_content)
      end

      p 'Parse error'
    else
      p 'The requested file could not be found'
    end
  end
end
```

It was my understanding that `YAML::load_file` returns a hash, and that [`Sass::Script::Value::Map`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/Map.html) would take a hash as input. But I get the following error I do not understand:

> C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.5.1/lib/sass/script/value/map.rb:22:in
>   `block in options=': undefined method `options=' for
>   "`first.value.in.yaml.file`":String (NoMethodError)

Using a yaml file like this:

```
first.value.in.yaml.file:
  name: MyName
  color: red
```

What is this options method, and how should I be converting the yaml file's contents into a SASS map?

(And if you know how to properly use a filename without it getting escaped, please share :) )

Comment: How do you use the `$ranges` variable?

Comment: @aristotll, at the moment I am not using it. Just the assignment already gives an error. Though I assumed that it could replace the `$map: ( foo: bar );` definition and I could then use map-get to obtain values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values in the map should be an instance of `Sass::Script::Value::Base` so that sass can use them.
But `Sass::Script::Value::Map.new` method does not do the conversion for us according to `sass` source code: [this](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/be02da0e955a4e172a3ad24d2d479947580849a1/lib/sass/script/value/map.rb#L15) and [this](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/1d9eedac5c42fc40c432f9f3224ea56f630d47ea/lib/sass/script/value/base.rb#L22-L26).

So  a conversion method is needed.

```
# @param [Hash]  value
# @return [Sass::Script::Value::Map or Sass::Script::Value::List] 
  def convert_to_base(value) # part of this function is copied from https://github.com/fabiofabbrucci/sass-yaml/blob/master/lib/sass-yaml.rb
    if value.is_a?(String) 
      return Sass::Script::Value::String.new(value.to_s)
    elsif value.is_a?(Array)
      value.each_with_index do |elem, i|
        value[i]= Sass::Script::Value::String.new(elem.to_s)
      end
      return Sass::Script::Value::List.new(value, ",")
    end
    result = Hash.new
    value.each {|the_key, the_value|
      result[convert_to_base(the_key)]=convert_to_base(the_value)
    }
    Sass::Script::Value::Map.new(result)
  end
```

Also changes `return Sass::Script::Value::Map.new(file_content)` to `return convert_to_base(file_content)`

Comment: Thanks, that somewhat makes sense. I will try this out in a few hours. It seems that the last line is missing a return though?

Comment: @Neograph734 Ruby implicitly returns the value of last evaluated expression in a method.

Comment: Awsome, I had to add another case for Fixnum's (coversion to Sass::Script::Value::Number) and now it is working. Full code is here: https://github.com/Neograph734/sass-yaml/blob/master/lib/sass-yaml.rb